# Where can I configure Outlook Web Access to encode messages in UTF-8?

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2007

Exchange 2007 | Exchange 2010 | Outlook web access

I've got a picky outbound mail gateway that doesn't like certain special characters in emails. The workaround is to configure the message to use Unicode (UTF-8) for the encoding format.

In Outlook, this is easy enough to set (File >> Options >> Advanced >> Preferred encoding for Outgoing Messages) but I'm not sure where I would configure this for OWA.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I assume this cannot be set on an individual user-by-user basis in OWA so I'm fine with Unicode (UTF-8) being the default encoding for all OWA users.

I've got a couple separate environments (one using Exchange 2007 and the other using Exchange 2010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older question, but here is the answer:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sv-SE/exchangesvrclients/thread/d991fad0-7bd8-4fd1-900f-b8bc4fe18733

Registry settings can be changed to enable UTF-8 Encoding for Exchange 2003 OWA when using Internet Explorer 5 or later versions.

=====

We can follow the steps below to change registry settings:

1.On the Exchange computer, log on by using the Exchange administrator account, and then start Registry Editor.

2.Locate and then click the following registry subkey:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSExchangeWEB\OWA

3.On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.

4.Type UseRegionalCharset for the name of the DWORD, and then press Enter.

5.Right-click the UseRegionalCharset DWORD value, and then click Modify.

6.In the Value data box, type 0, and then click OK.

7.Close Registry Editor to save your changes.